# Javascript date format method

Tags: javascript

Having trouble with this:

```
var now = new Date();
var timestamp = now.format("dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:ss") + " (" + GetLoggedUserName() + ")";
```

I get: Object doesn't support property or method 'format'

I was sure this worked before though on other projects..

Comment: other projects may have had js library for date (datejs, momentjs, etc)

Comment: You can always check the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to see all available properties for the Date constructor.

Answer (score 6):

The `format()` function is not standard for `Date` objects in javascript.

You have most likely seen this in an application running a date formatting library such as moment.js.

http://momentjs.com/

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
```

---

Your example could be rewrote in moment.js like this:

```
var timestamp = moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss") + " (" + GetLoggedUserName() + ")";
```